# I want to write the institute name in two lines. However, when I try to use "\\", the whole alignment has been changed

Tags: line-breaking, titles, ieeetran

I want to write the institute name in two lines. However, when I try to use "\\", the whole alignment has been changed.

[image]

I want to keep " Department of Computer Science" in first line & "and Software Engineering" in second line.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please do not post pictures of code, but copy the code in your question and provide a so called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so others can easily handle your problem..

Answer (score 5):

You can't just insert `\\` inside `\textit` to break the lines (`\textit{<stuff> \\ <more stuff>}`). Use `\textit{<stuff>} \\ \textit{<more stuff>}`

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Some IEEE paper}

\author{
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Author One}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{%
    Some University \\
    email@example.com}
  \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Author Two}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{%
    \textit{Department of Computer Science} \\
    \textit{and Software Engineering} \\
    \textit{University X} \\
    email@example.com}
  \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Author Three}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{%
    Some University\\
    email@example.com}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```